# Mongodb find $gt on string returns unexpected results and $lt works fine

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Mongo shell find({"name":{**$gt**:"b"}} returns result data including **b**

My data

```
db.users.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("569651d2560c18656fd69133"), "name" : "bob" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("569651d7560c18656fd69134"), "name" : "arpit" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("569651dd560c18656fd69135"), "name" : "cat" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("569651e5560c18656fd69136"), "name" : "dog" }
```

my find operation

```
db.users.find({"name":{$gt:"b"}}, {"name":true, "_id":false})

{ "name" : "bob" }
{ "name" : "cat" }
{ "name" : "dog" }
```

However find **$lt** returns correct results

```
db.users.find({"name":{$lt:"c"}}, {"name":true, "_id":false})

{ "name" : "bob" }
{ "name" : "arpit" }
```

I don't understand why "bob" is being returned in $gt.

Comment: The `$gt` comparison considers the entire string, not just the first character. And `'bob' > 'b'` because it's a longer string.

Comment: Strings are compared [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). "bo" > "b"

Comment: instead you should try {$gte: 'c'}